# Get Element Name with Click Event Handler on Panels

Tags: c#, winforms, events, panel

I have a question regarding event handling on C#:

I have 5 Panels, and I'd like to get each Name Property on Click.

I have tried the following on Form1_Click():

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panelClicked = sender as Panel;

    if (panelClicked != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(panelClicked.Name);
    }
}
```

Wouldn't this work for Panel Elements?
It doesn't for me. Any idea?

Comment: That could be WPF, WinForms or WebForms code (all have a `Panel` control). Which are you using?

Comment: WinForms. No WPF, neither WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the eventhandler to each panel and not to the form.
you simply do this :

```
panel1.Click += Form1_Click;
panel2.Click += Form1_Click;
panel3.Click += Form1_Click;
panel4.Click += Form1_Click;
panel5.Click += Form1_Click;
```

and you are good to go.
You might want to rename the eventhandler and remove the click handler of the form itself. But I hope you get the idea.
I coded the eventhandler attaching here, but it also works via the designer. The idea is totally the same, because the signatures match you can use the same eventhandler for multiple controls.

In case you don't like the above there are variations like so :

```
foreach(Control childControl in control.Controls)
{
     if (childControl is Panel) childControl.Click += Form1_Click;
}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid. I have like 60 Panels which needs to get clicked. And doing that for every panel is a real pain. Any alternative?

Comment: You can iterate over the children of the parent control and attach the handler in the code like I did here, you can check the type of control the child is using 'is Panel'

Comment: It should be added that the code to get at the Names is: `string name = ((Control)sender).Name;`

Comment: @TaW panelClicked  is a Panel and that is a control so the casting is not needed.

Comment: But `sender` is `object`, so casting __is__ necessary. `Control` is simply the lowest class possible..

Comment: op has following code : Panel panelClicked = sender as Panel; so cast is not needed

Comment: whoops, missed that part

Comment: Only thing I'd suggest is using `controls.OfType<Panel>`. Otherwise, good answer, it's all OP needs to make something.